# how to convert (Select $users from users where $type == '1' && $type == '2'); in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i have a very little background about codeigniter, but i really can't understand how to use the "or_where" and the question above. so my code starts here:

```
function get_all(){
$this->db->where('type', '2');
$this->db->or_where('type ==', '2'); 
$query = $this->db->get('users');
$res = $query->result();
echo $res;
}
```

Comment: `type ==1 && type ==2`? will always return empty set.I guess you want or

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close:

```
$this->db->select('users');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where('type', '1');
$this->db->or_where('type ==', '2');
$query = $this->db->get();
$res = $query->result();
```

I haven't tried that, but it should work.

Comment: CASE CLOSED. THANK YOU SIR! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('type' => '1', 'type' => '2');

$this->db->where($array);
```

`$this->db->where` can take associative array as argument. So pass the keys and  values as associative array. It will work.

Comment: This query  will always return empty set.

Comment: it returns only the last statement >> 'type' =>'2'

Comment: CASE CLOSED. THANK YOU SIR! :)